# jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, mouseenter

I'm using an anchor tag with an image as a hyperlink and I would like the image also to change on mouseover/mouseleave. The hyperlink works but the mouse/image change bit doesn't.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery('document').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/check_cross_hilite.png');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/check_cross_trans.png');
  }
}, 'p#title');
```

The surprising thing for me is that very similar jQuery code on the same page is working OK. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `jQuery(document)` not `jQuery('document')` as `'document'` refers a element selector which will look for an element with tagname `document` like `<document>...</document>`

```
jQuery(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/check_cross_hilite.png');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/check_cross_trans.png');
  }
}, 'p#title');
```

Comment: Also make sure DOM is ready for it, if <img> got added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try this remove single quote from document.

```
jQuery(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/check_cross_hilite.png');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/check_cross_trans.png');
  }
}, 'p#title');
```

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)